Group array of objects by property name
I have an array that I need group by a certain property ("name").
[
    {
        
        "name": "cor​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "value": "#e61809​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"
    },
    {
         "name": "cor​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",        
        "value": "#3e7555​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"
    },
    {
        "name": "tamanho​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "value": "m​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"
    },
    {
        "name": "tamanho ​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "value": "L​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"
    }
]

and I need to convert to:
   { cor: [{
        
        "name": "cor​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "value": "#e61809​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍‌‍​​‍​​​‌​‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‍‌‍‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"
    },
    {
         "name": "cor​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",        
        "value": "#3e7555​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​​​​‍​​‍‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‌‍​​​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"
    }],
    tamanho:[{
        "name": "tamanho​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "value": "m​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‌‍​‌​‌‍‌​​‍‌​‌‌‌‍​‌​‍​​​​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‍​‌​‍‌​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌​‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​​‍‌​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌​​​​‌​‌‍‌‌​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‌‍​​‍​‍‌​​​​​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌​‌‍‌‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"
    },
    {
        "name": "tamanho ​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‍‍‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "value": "L​​​​‌‍​‍​‍‌‍‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍‍‌‌‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍​‍​‍​​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌‍​‍​‍​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‍​‍​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‍‌‌‍‌‍‌​‌‍‌‌​‌‌​​‌​‍‌‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‍‍​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‌‍​‍‌‍​‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​‍‌‍​​‌‌‍‍​‌‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​​‌​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍‌​‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌‍​‌‍‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‌​‌‍‌​‍‍‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‍‌​‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌​​‌​‍​​‍​‌‍‌‍‌‍‌​​‌​​​​‌​‌‍​‌​‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‍​​​‌‍​​‍‌​‌​‌‍​‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌‌‌‍​‍​‍‌‌‍​‌​‌​​‌​​​​‍​​‌​​‍​‌‍‌‌‌‍​‌​​‌‌‍​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​‌‍‌‌​​‌‍‌‌​‌‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‌‌‍‍‌‌​​‍‌‍‌​​‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‍‍​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌​‌​‍‌‍‍‌‌‍​‍‌‌‌‌‌​‌‍‌‌‌​​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌​​‌‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​​‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍‌‍​‌​‍​​​‍‌‍‌​​‍​​‌​​‍‌​‍​‌‍​‍‌‍‌‌​​​‌‍​‍‌‌​​‍​​‍​‍‌‌​‌‌‌​‌​​‍‍‌‌‍‌‍​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌‍‌‌​‍​‍‌‌",
        "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"
    }]
}

const groupedMap = variantsAttrs.reduce(
            (entryMap, e) => entryMap.set(e.name, [...entryMap.get(e.name)||[], e]),
            new Map()
        )


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking]

I've rolled back your last change because it invalidated a valid answer. If you want to ask a different question, please post a new question.

This question is similar to: How can I group an array of objects by key?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you want a Map, use Map.groupBy():


const variantsAttrs = [{"name":"cor","value":"#e61809","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"},{"name":"cor","value":"#3e7555","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"},{"name":"tamanho","value":"m","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"},{"name":"tamanho","value":"L","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"}]

const result = Map.groupBy(variantsAttrs, o => o.name)

console.log(result) // check the browser's console



To create an 2d array after grouping by key, use Object.groupBy(), and then convert back to any array with Array.values():


const variantsAttrs = [{"name":"cor","value":"#e61809","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"},{"name":"cor","value":"#3e7555","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"},{"name":"tamanho","value":"m","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"},{"name":"tamanho","value":"L","sku":"SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"}]

const result = Object.values(
  Object.groupBy(variantsAttrs, o => o.name)
)

console.log(result)




You're almost there with reduce. I simplify it a bit


const variantsAttrs = [{

    "name": "cor",
    "value": "#e61809",
    "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"
  },
  {
    "name": "cor",
    "value": "#3e7555",
    "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"
  },
  {
    "name": "tamanho",
    "value": "m",
    "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9"
  },
  {
    "name": "tamanho",
    "value": "L",
    "sku": "SKU-BICI-EST-TREKMAD-SLR9-1"
  }
]

const output = variantsAttrs.reduce((current, item) => {
  if (!current[item.name]) {
    current[item.name] = [];
  }

  current[item.name].push(item);

  return current;
}, {});

console.log(output);




Hi Nick. Thanks. I update the output format. Need you touch your anwser. I thank you again.

OP has changed their required output after this answer was posted.

console.log(Object.values(output)); @LeonelMatiasDomingos can you check this

Not workin @Nick

@Nick Vu now i have TypeError: Object.groupBy is not a function

node upgarded and is ok. I made my day, thanks again
